# dependent: :destroy does not work in a simple scenario

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Although its straightforward, but it does not work,

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

Company.find(39).destroy()
# what I expect is to destroy all users that has company_id equals 39, 
#but that won't happen
```

So, what's up?

EDIT, here is what I do in rails c:

```
[88] pry(main)> User.create!(email: "as3now29@gmail.com", company_id: 29, password:"1234567890")
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'as3now29@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `encrypted_password`
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("company_id", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["company_id", 29], ["created_at", "2014-09-02 08:59:29.702141"], ["email", "as3now29@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$FHsDMbEhmXyNZGz685inSOv6f7meDkxyN2rglmc.99F.lZeYOnTCG"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-02 08:59:29.702141"]]
   (51.2ms)  commit transaction
=> #<User id: 42, email: "as3now29@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FHsDMbEhmXyNZGz685inSOv6f7meDkxyN2rglmc.99F...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-09-02 08:59:29", updated_at: "2014-09-02 08:59:29", number: nil, name: nil, car_id: nil, company_id: 29, hardware_id: nil>
[89] pry(main)> Company.find(29).destroy
  Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 29]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = ?  [["id", 29]]
   (12.4ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Company id: 29, created_at: "2014-09-02 08:59:16", updated_at: "2014-09-02 08:59:16", user_id: nil, admin_email: nil, name: nil>
[91] pry(main)> User.all.select(:id, :number, :email, :company_id, :hardware_id)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id", "users"."number", "users"."email", "users"."company_id", "users"."hardware_id" FROM "users"
=> [ #<User id: 42, email: "as3now29@gmail.com", number: nil, company_id: 29, hardware_id: nil>]
```

Comment: what if you use destroy without parenthesis?

Comment: I will check now, one moment!

Comment: The same result, it will not destroy the user

Comment: this is strange, because code looks just fine. And you are sure, some users do have company_id == 39? Does it destroys the company or it's at all do nothing?

Comment: it will destroy the company, but the user still there .. there must be something wrong,,

Comment: hm... just curious, why your company has user_id attribute? it is the user who created the company, smth like this?

Comment: yes, its the admin user who can add users for the company

Comment: What if you try Company.destroy(29). Butprobably it does the same.. do not know man what's the reason

Comment: The same thing, the user is not destroyed

Comment: May be because the user is used for devise?

Comment: don't think so, you would easily destroy any user no matter what dependancies or whatever he has

Comment: I found the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I found the answer, I have to remove user_id column from Company, otherwise it will not work, so there must be a link table to link Company with owner users